# Returning dynamic info to HTTP request which triggers a step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

TLDR: How do I pass dynamic data to my HTTP response from a step function lambda triggered by HTTP?

I have a step function state machine triggered by a HTTP request. It's set up using the serverless framework with the [serverless-step-functions](https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-step-functions) plugin, but I'd imagine the solution is general/can be applied to my template.

Using the default configuration for a http handler such as

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
      events:
        - http:
            path: hello
            method: GET
      definition:
        ...
```

Returns an ARN and a start date (which obviously isn't ideal as it exposes my account ID etc)

```
{"executionArn":"arn:aws:states:x:x:execution:hellostepfunc1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx","startDate":1.68062354019E9}
```

I can configure a response template to override this

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
      events:
        - http:
            path: hello
            method: GET
            response:
              headers:
                Content-Type: "'application/json'"
              template:
                application/json: |
                  {
                    "status": 200,
                    "info": "OK"
                  }
      definition:
```

Which works fine and responds with the following to the HTTP request as expected

```
{"status": 200,"info": "OK"}
```

However, I want to return information from the lambda function such as error state or a different status code etc.

- I have tried [ResultPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html) on the state machine step but this just affects the data sent to the next step, and doesn't change the HTTP response
- I have tried modifying the template with variables but they reference the original ones (arn and start date), not the ones returned from my function

```
template:
  application/json: |
    {
       "statusCode": "$input.path('$.statusCode')", // blank (i have returned it in my function)
       "body": "$input.body", // returns ARN and start date
       "path": "$input.path('$')" // returns ARN and start date
    }
```

I have considered just calling a standard API Gateway lambda, returning my HTTP response from there and using the Step Functions SDK to trigger the state machine separately but that feels convoluted.

How do I pass dynamic data to my HTTP response from a step function lambda triggered by HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the data from the `output` field returned to [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) by the [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) [StartSyncExecution API Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartSyncExecution.html#StepFunctions-StartSyncExecution-response-output).

You can find a more complete example (using SAM not Serverless, but it should be analogous) here: [Trigger via Amazon API Gateway and wait for response](https://serverlessland.com/workflows/synchronous-api).